# What’s the relationship between the variables in $E[(Y-(b_0+b_1X))^2]$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(b_0+b_i x_i))^2$ in linear regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

From Section 1.2 and 1.3 of [these notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/01/lecture-01.pdf), for some r.v. $X$ and $Y$, if $MSE(b_0, b_1) = E[(Y-(b_0+b_1X))^2]$, it was found that $\beta_1 = \frac{Cov[X,Y]}{Var[X]}$ and $\beta_0 = E[Y]-\beta_1E[X]$ are the values of $b_0$ and $b_1$ that minimizes the MSE. On page 7 it is stated that no assumptions are made in this regarding the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ or their relationship to each other.

I’m trying to figure out how to link the above to simple least squares discussed in the notes of a [later lecture](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/04/lecture-04.pdf) where $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$, $X$ may be deterministic or random, and the goal is to find $\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1$ (as estimators of $\beta_0, \beta_1$) which minimizes $\hat{MSE}(b_0, b_1)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(b_0+b_i x_i))^2$.

1. How are $Y$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$ related from the two cases?
2. How is $MSE(b_0, b_1) = E[(Y-(b_0+b_1X))^2]$ computed if $X$ is non-random?
3. If $X$ and $\epsilon$ (in $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$) are independent, is it correct to write $E[\epsilon] = 0$ and  $Var[\epsilon] = \sigma^2$ instead of $E[\epsilon | X = x] = 0$ and  $Var[\epsilon | X = x] = \sigma^2$ (per page 1 of the notes in the second link)?

Comment: The variables in expectations are the idealized true values (based on an idealized data generating process). The ones with hats are called estimates and it is your fair attempt/method to find the idealized values. Minimizing empirical MSE is one such method.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc My main confusion is that the notes specify that $Y$  in the $MSE$ equation can be of any distribution but the $Y$ in $\hat{MSE}$ (which is supposed to be a consistent estimator of $MSE$) is assumed to be equal to $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$. It seems like the latter case imposes greater restrictions on $Y$ so it's not obvious to me why $\hat{MSE}$ can be considered an estimator of $MSE$.

Comment: Ideal Y in MSE can be anything. Y in $\hat{MSE}$ is assumed to be say linear gaussian if you believe that ideal Y is gaussian. If your assumption is correct than your estimate has optimality properties. If not it is still an attempt to get a suboptimal solution, which sometimes will be awfully wrong.

Comment: Roughly speaking, $E[(Y-(b_0+b_1X))^2]$ is the population version and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(b_0+b_1 x_i))^2$ is the sample version. The latter formulation is often employed when both $x$ and $y$ are deterministic.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc So when we assume the $Y$ in $\hat{MSE}$ to be $\beta_0+\beta_1 X + \epsilon$ (linear gaussian) we are also making this same assumption for the $Y$ in $MSE$?